# nls error during the parameter estimation of power law with exponential cutoff distribution in R

Tags: r, parameters, nls, mle, power-law

I want to fit mydata with several known distributions, `power law with exponential cutoff` distribution is one of the candidates.

`fitdistr` function in package `fitdistrplus` is one of good methods to use for the parameter estimation using MLE, or MME, or QME.

But `power law with exponential cutoff` is not the base probability function according to [CRAN Task View: Probability Distributions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Distributions.html) , so I try the `nls` function.

The pdf of `power law with exponential cutoff` is   `f(x;α,λ)=C*x^(−α)*exp(−λ*x)`

First, I generate some random values to replace my real data:

```
data <- rlnorm(1000,0.6,1.23)
h <- hist(data,breaks=1000,plot=FALSE)
x <- h$mids
y <- h$density
```

Then, I use `nls` function to conduct parameter estimation:

`nls(y~c*x^(-a)*exp(-b*x),start=list(a=1,b=1,c=1))`

But it does not work and always throws one of these two errors:

`Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model`

Or: `singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates`

Before posting, I have read almost all the previous posts and google, there are several reasons for the errors:

1. bad start values for the `nls`. I tried a lot, but it does not work.
2. some negative values or values less than 1 or values equal to `Inf` may be generated. I tried to do the data cleaning, also, it does not work.

What should I do now? Or are there some other better methods to do the parameter estimation of `power law with exponential cutoff`? I need your help, thank you!

Comment: Your example above won't work as you have not passed either `x` or `y`, as data, in the `nls` call - neither have you used the example data. That said, as an alternative to `nls`, you can try `minpack.lm::nlsLM`which  uses the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm, so is a lot more forgiving on starting values.

Comment: @user20650 sorry, I forget it and update my questions now, please check it again, thank you

Comment: Using the random data produced from `set.seed(1)`, both `nls(y ~ c* x^(-a)* exp(-b* x),  start=list(a=1,b=1,c=1))` and `;minpack.lm::nlsLM(y ~ c* x^(-a)* exp(-b* x), start=list(a=1,b=1,c=1))` converge.at your start values..

Comment: bIf you want netter help on techniques to chose sensible start values systematically, you could try asking that question on http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @user20650 amazing, why random values from `set.seed(1)` work?

Comment: Is the question the topic of CV?

Comment: when you generate random numbers it is good practice to set the seed so that you can reproduce the analysis. Why these work in particular - random luck!

Comment: Your question, as it is written is not on topic for CV, however, if asking for a statistical method / process to generate sensible starting values for the function would be.